# Mining for rpc set number of threads

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, rpc

In the monero-wallet-cli having connected to a public node that accepts or requires payment via mining how does one adjust the number of threads used for the mining payment.

For example, when you run the help command after starting your wallet you can see:

```
start_mining [<number_of_threads>] [bg_mining] [ignore_battery]
```

But for the rpc mining there is no [] parameter:

```
start_mining_for_rpc
```

It seems that start_mining_for_rpc defaults to 1 thread. I believe server hosts may want to increase the payment and running on multiple threads would allow for that.

Is there any non-obvious way to increase the rpc mining thread count?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to mine with multiple threads in monero-wallet-cli for the mine-for-RPC system.